Differential of a connection form of a Principal Bundle
In Hamilton's "Mathematical Gauge Theory", he defines the curvature as follows,
$$F(X, Y) = dA(\pi^H(X), \pi^H(Y))$$
However, he hasn't defined what $d$ is for a vector-valued one form is.
He later also refers to the formula,
$$ dA(X,Y) = L_X(A(Y)) - L_X(A(Y)) -A([X,Y]) $$ which refers to a formula in the appendix that was for 2-forms, not vector valued 2-forms.
How should I interpret the extension of $d$ to vector-valued forms? Should I just take the second equation above as it's definition?

Looking at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form, since this is a Lie Algebra valued form, it looks like one can just take the usual exterior derivative for each component given a basis for $\mathfrak{g}$.

This is correct, yes.

As you have figured out, one basically just fixes a basis and applies it for each component, and the definition is independent of your choice of basis. This is a convention for vector space valued forms :)
However, to provide another point of view, from a general perspective: There is the notion of exterior covariant derivatives, an exterior derivative for vector bundle valued forms, but which may not be a differential. In Hamilton's book you cited this is defined in Definition 5.12.3 for example. The idea in such contexts is often to fix a connection in order to lift the vector fields to derive something with values in a vector bundle. That is, for a vector bundle $E \to M$ over a smooth manifold $M$, equipped with a vector bundle connection $\nabla$ one defines for all $\omega \in \Omega^k(M; E)$ ($k$-forms with values in $E$, $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$)
\begin{align} 
\left(\mathrm{d}^\nabla \omega\right)(X_0, \dots, X_k)
&:=
\sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^i ~ \nabla_{X_i} \left( \omega\left(X_0, \dots, \hat{X}_i, \dots, X_k\right) \right)
\\
&\hspace{1cm}
+ \sum_{0 \leq i < j \leq k} (-1)^{i+j} ~ \omega \left( \left[ X_i, X_j \right], X_0, \dots, \hat{X}_i, \dots, \hat{X}_j, \dots, X_k \right)
\end{align}
for all $X_0, \dots, X_k \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ (vector fields on $M$), where the hat denotes omission of the corresponding vector field. This describes a differential (= it squares to zero) if and only if $\nabla$ is flat.
Back to your question: It is often a convention to regard vector spaces as trivial vector bundles and then assuming the canonical trivial definitions following the trivialisation. That is, let $V$ be a vector bundle and set $E = M \times V$, the trivial $V$-vector bundle over $M$. A $V$-valued $k$-form is equivalent to a $k$-form with values in $E$ in this case. In order to define an exterior covariant derivative one has to fix some vector bundle connection. As a canonical choice, one can set $\nabla = \nabla^0$, the canonical flat connection, i.e., the unique vector bundle connection whose parallel sections are precisely the constant sections (given the trivialisation of $E$). Given the global frame of constant sections in $E$, $\nabla^0 \nu$ for any section $\nu$ of $E$ acts like the Lie derivative of each component with respect to the global frame of constant sections. Thus, many also write $\nabla^0_X = L_X$. If you insert this now in the equation above and set $k =1$, then you get precisely the definition you were looking at :) Observe, $\nabla^0$ is flat by construction and thus $\mathrm{d}^{\nabla^0}$ is a differential and due to its canonical structure and relation to $L$ given a global trivialisation, one simply writes $\mathrm{d}$ to emphasize the component-wise de Rham differential.

Nice answer. I've been trying to piece this picture together since some texts I've looked don't mention or define exterior covariant derivatives whereas others do. This was a nice unifying answer. In fact this, might make for a nice addition to the wikipedia pages on exterior covariant derivatives or vector valued forms.

:) Indeed, sometimes it is useful to have a more general perspective; in that example: one could now question what happens in the theory like gauge theory if one decides not taking the canonical flat connection $\nabla^0$, even if $E$ is still assumed to be trivial. Essentially asking what happens if one decides not taking canonical structures, even if available :)
